# MemcachePool::get(): Server localhost (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Network timeout

Tags: php, windows, tcp, memcached

I have been working with Memcache and PHP for a long time and was everything great but now I have been getting this error after every 10 to 15 minutes.

```
MemcachePool::get(): Server localhost (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Network timeout
```

I thought it might be due to Firewall or something like that so I turned of my Firewall but yet didn't stop giving this message.

After every error I have to restart my memcache.

And it's Memcache not with D on windows 7 machine with PHP 5.4 MSVC9 TS version. I can not understand what to do now with this **Network Timeout** issue. What can be done to solve this.

Currently, currently I have only one local machine with windows 7 so cannot make a cluster of Memcache or install Memcache(D).

Unsure if it is a memcache Daemon or client issue.

Comment: Are you using a persistent connection? I was using a persistent connection (w/ either `pconnect` or `addServer`'s `$persistent` arg), switching to `connect` or using `false` for the persistent arg, I no longer have this problem (so far...). Win 7 x86_64, PHP 5.5.9 x86 TS VC11 API=20121113, memcache 3.0.8 rev 329835, memcached-win64-1.4.4-14

Comment: @zamnuts I don't remember since it has been 4 months now but I finally solved it at that time. Thanks for your kind comment. May be someone else can be benefited by this.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarDumrai HOW do you solve it? you could add solution as an answer of your own question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, with php on Windows 10 and Memcached installed on Ubuntu (running in the Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Im my case, the problem was that `localhost` resolves to `[::1]`:

```
>ping localhost
Pinging SURFACE-PRO-FRA [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
```

And Memcached by default listens only on 127.0.0.1.

To solve the issue, you can make Memcached listens also on the ipv6:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/memcached.conf
```

Replace

```
-l 127.0.0.1
```

with:

```
-l 127.0.0.1,::1
```

And then

```
sudo service memcached restart
```

Or alternatively, make your app connect to *127.0.0.1* instead of *localhost*.